# Create new Kotlin console and create a test got TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests

Tags: intellij-idea, junit5

Create new Kotlin console application

with Build system IntelliJ Project SDK java1.8
and Test framework JUnit5. Target JVM 1.8

Any idea to fix it?

and create a test.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*

internal class SparseVectorTest {

    @Test
    fun dotProductCase1() {
        val v1 = SparseVector(intArrayOf(1,0,1,2,9))
        val v2 = SparseVector(intArrayOf(0,3,0,4,0))
        assertEquals(8,v1.dotProduct(v2))
    }

    @Test
    fun dotProductCase2() {
        val v1 = SparseVector(intArrayOf(0,9,2,0,0))
        val v2 = SparseVector(intArrayOf(0,0,0,1,2))
        assertEquals(0,v1.dotProduct(v2))
    }

    @Test
    fun getNums() {
        val v1 = SparseVector(intArrayOf(0,1,0,0,0))
        assertEquals(intArrayOf(0,1,0,0,0),v1.nums)
    }
}
```

It compile pass but failed at run time with error

```
TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
```

Also try with jdk13.0.2 still got the same result

Answer (score 0):

Use Gradle Kotlin as a build system and its working fine